# Adding styles to component defined using `defineComponent`

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, components

Is it possible to somehow add styles to a component I defined using the `defineComponent` function in Vue 3?

Let's use this as an example:

```js
import { defineComponent, h } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TestComponent',
  setup() {
    return () => h('div', ['test'])
  }
})
```

I'd also like the styles to be scoped.

Sadly, having the component in a `.vue` file with a `<style>` tag is not an option for my use case.

Comment: Just to be clear, `defineComponent` can be used in `.vue` SFCs with style tag and is not the source of your restriction.  The real restriction is the component being a non-SFC `.js` file. In this case, you have to import a stylesheet and scope your styles the old fashioned way, with a unique id or classname on your root element which is then used by all your CSS selectors.

Comment: I know I can use `defineComponent` in a `.vue` file, however, the reason why I cannot use it in this way is that I want to be able to replace the default content of some slots in my Nuxt Layers & the only way I was able to make it work like I wanted was to define a function that accepts the default content for the slots in an argument & returns `defineComponent()`